# How to create a table based on query with variable declaration in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I would like to create a table for a funnel query that has a declaration for days variable.If I use the query without the create statement the query runs fine. When I tried to add the `select * into ..from` I get two errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'. 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

How can save the query with the days declaration into a new table

```
select * into tbl60D_AlertsFunnel from (
    declare @d date = getdate() - 60
    select sum(IP) AS IP ,sum(sentCount) sentCount, sum(readCount) readCount, sum(NumberOfOpensPerEmail) OpenNumber
    from (
    select COUNT(distinct CAST(sm.IP AS nvarchar(20))) as IP
      , count(distinct v.iditem) sentCount
      , MAX(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as OpenDateShort -- v.iditem is for sent, sm.OpenDate IS FOR OPEN
      ,count(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as NumberOfOpensPerEmail
      , count(distinct sm.iditem) readCount
    from fff.dbo.v_rep_MessageQueue v (nolock)
     left join [FF].[dbo].[tblMessageOpenedSMTP] sm
      on v.IdItem = sm.iditem
    -- and cast(sm.OpenDate as date)  > @d
    where v.IdMessageType = 20
     and V.DateScheduled > @d
     group by sm.IP
    ) d
    ) j
```

Comment: You can't declare a variable inside a query

Comment: take this row `declare @d date = getdate() - 60` and put it **before** the `select...` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As had been pointed out in comments, your query should be like

```
declare @d date = getdate() - 60 -- outside the select


select * into tbl60D_AlertsFunnel from (

    select sum(IP) AS IP ,sum(sentCount) sentCount, sum(readCount) readCount, sum(NumberOfOpensPerEmail) OpenNumber
    from (
    select COUNT(distinct CAST(sm.IP AS nvarchar(20))) as IP
      , count(distinct v.iditem) sentCount
      , MAX(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as OpenDateShort -- v.iditem is for sent, sm.OpenDate IS FOR OPEN
      ,count(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as NumberOfOpensPerEmail
      , count(distinct sm.iditem) readCount
    from fff.dbo.v_rep_MessageQueue v (nolock)
     left join [FF].[dbo].[tblMessageOpenedSMTP] sm
      on v.IdItem = sm.iditem
    -- and cast(sm.OpenDate as date)  > @d
    where v.IdMessageType = 20
     and V.DateScheduled > @d
     group by sm.IP
    ) d
    ) j
```

**Explanation:**

Your problem was that while this query worked for you

```
declare @d date = getdate() - 60
    select sum(IP) AS IP ,sum(sentCount) sentCount, sum(readCount) readCount, sum(NumberOfOpensPerEmail) OpenNumber
    from (
    select COUNT(distinct CAST(sm.IP AS nvarchar(20))) as IP
      , count(distinct v.iditem) sentCount
      , MAX(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as OpenDateShort -- v.iditem is for sent, sm.OpenDate IS FOR OPEN
      ,count(cast(sm.OpenDate as date)) as NumberOfOpensPerEmail
      , count(distinct sm.iditem) readCount
    from fff.dbo.v_rep_MessageQueue v (nolock)
     left join [FF].[dbo].[tblMessageOpenedSMTP] sm
      on v.IdItem = sm.iditem
    -- and cast(sm.OpenDate as date)  > @d
    where v.IdMessageType = 20
     and V.DateScheduled > @d
     group by sm.IP
    ) d
```

you wanted to nest this as sub query to `select into` statement, but failed to move the declaration outside.